# Right way to change titles based on domain website is being accessed from?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a web application that has two names/domains pointing to it. I have it setup in IIS as one website with bindings for both domains.

I want
1) the logo to be different depending on which domain it's being accessed from
2) Various places around the website I use the name (ie; about us, "i created **__** because.."). I want the name to be based on the domain accessing it.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Host that is writen on the url you can use the `Request.Url.Host`

```
string sTheUrlHost = Request.Url.Host.ToLowerInvariant();
```

Now base on this you can change the content of your pages. For example for this site the `Request.Url.Host` will show: stackoverflow.com